# MySQL relationships: Bid with products and users

Tags: mysql, database, data-modeling

I have a simple site where users can bid on a product. The model looks like this:
[image]
Obviously different users can bid, so how do I draw the missing link to the 'users' table?

I'm a little confused whether to use identifying or non-identifying relationship.
Updated:

### [image]

Comment: this seems like a pretty good start, though i would still index your look up many to many look up tables for optimization reasons.  there are debates to this but i still add them.  which missing link to the 'users' table? please explain that a bit :)

Comment: @Ben: That was my mistake. Edited now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say: *"... **users can bid on a product.**"*

This suggests that there is a relationship (Bids) between Users and Products. You could name it `user_bids_on_product` or just `bid`.

I would remove the relationship between `user` and `product` (unless it means something else like the owner of a product) and unify your `bids` and `bids_has_product` into one table:

```
user_bids_on_product
--------------------
product_id  FK to product
user_id     FK to user
price
```

The `(product_id, user_id)` should **not** be the Primary Key for this table, as we assume a user can bid multiple times on a product.

You could add a surrogate `id` and make that the PK or add a `bid_number` column and make the compound `(product_id, user_id, bid_number)` the PK. You could alternatively make the `(product_id, bid_number)` the PK (the `bid_number` could mark the order of the bids per product, like an auction in this case). I think that's up to you to decide.

Identifying relationships:

[image: Bid table with identifying relationships]

---

Non-identifying relationships:

[image: Bid table with non-identifying relationships]

Comment: I have to have the relationship btw user and product, since products are owned by users. I updated the diagram. Makes sense?

Comment: No, what you have is not what I suggested. This design (the current), means that a bid can be related to many products and also related to many users. I don't see how this can have any real meaning.

Comment: And price would be better be `DECIMAL`, not `VARCHAR`.

Comment: Please, don't remove the original design (image) when you edit a question. Future readers will get confused. If you want to add one more image, that's fine.

Comment: Good point. Makes sense that one product can have many bids, and multiple users can have multiple bids. I updated the diagram

Comment: makes sense to have it this way? just to have a simple bid system.

Comment: To decide whether to use identifying (or not) relationship, you'll have to decide first: Do you want to keep bids for a product if you delete that product? Do you want to keep bids from a user if that user is deleted from the db?

Comment: If you say No to both, then I'd use the identifying (on both lines) version, as in my image. But note that if you delete a user (and you have `ON DELETE CASCADE`), the auctions that he has taken part will not hold all details from then on (his bids would be removed).

Comment: Interesting. So, i would need to choose    ON DELETE NO ACTION ? What is the ideal solution here? If a user is deleted, i want to still keep bids and ratings on the product (i would just change bid/rating-user to something default). If a product is deleted, i want to still keep ratings on the user. Any ideas?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8223/discussion-between-user1163859-and-ypercube)

Comment: Then you should set the 2 FK with `ON DELETE SET NULL`. That would mean that the 2 columns (`user_id` and `product_id`) are nullable, so tehy can't be used for being part of the PK. So, you may define just the `bid_number` as PK (changing it to `bid_id` perhaps to be consistent in naming).

Answer (score 1):

A User can make one Bid on a Product; a User can Bid on more than one Product; a Product can have more than one Bid; a Bid is associated with only a single Product.

I think you need to have a relationship between a User and the Bids they make.  It's one-to-many.

Another question regarding your updated diagram: would a User assign a Rating to a Product, in much the same way they give a Bid?  Is that worth tracking?  If yes, I'd have a relationship between User and Rating.

Answer (score 0):

A simple identifying relationship b/w users and bids makes sense, bids can't exist without a user.

Its a simple one to many relations, as users "has_many" bids.